# Time in 12-hour format in Control M

Tags: control-m, service-control-manager

How to send email Notification with below date and Time format in header of email

```
2020-12-31  01-30-25 PM
```

I am able to derive time by creating 3 local variables then concatenating  them but time is displaying in 24-hr format

```
%%HOURS            %%SUBSTR %%TIME 1 2
%%MINUTES          %%SUBSTR %%TIME 3 2
%%SECONDS          %%SUBSTR %%TIME 5 2
```

Contaminating above local variables  %%HOURS.:%%MINUTES.:%%SECONDS

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that is the only system variable that Control-M supplies (in terms of time). To be honest, there's not much demand for 12 hour based times. The only way would be to set your own Control-M user variable by displaying the system time and setting the variable like so (the pre- or post command field is good for this).

Comment: could you please help me how do I create user variable and derive time in 12-hr format. Appreciate your help

Comment: Then you will need to display the system time in 12 hour output and pipe the result into the ctmvar utility, which sets Control-M variables - ctmvar -action set -var \%\%\\12HR_TIME -varexpr "your_input_here"